# FPGA resource estimation

Tags: resources, vhdl, slice, fpga, state-machine

I'm estimating my resource usage by counting the number of flip flop I need for a component. For example, when I estimate it for `ins_controldata` (simple counter and some I/O), I use 32 flipflops. When I look at the detailed map report of this component, Section 13 - Utilization by Hierarchy, I see that my estimations are close to the number of slice registers used for this component. Every slice has 4 LUTs and 8 flipflops.

Now when I do the same for my finite state machine,  `inst_xtm640`, I estimate my flipflop usage around 43 (including the 3 flipflops needed for the 6 states). When I look at the map report, I see my estimation is more or  less correct (+-10% error). But the number of slices needed are much higher than the slice register and LUTs needed. It's 40 when you look at the used LUTs, it should only be around 20.

Why are extra slices used for this component? Is it for speed optimization ?

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Module               | Partition | Slices*       | Slice Reg     | LUTs          |                                                            
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ++inst_controldata   |           | 6/6           | 35/35         | 20/20         |
| +++inst_xtm640       |           | 40/40         | 57/57         | 88/88         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Edit: 
I think I found it myself but other inputs are always welcome:

Not all slices are fully used. So it doesn't mean if I use 88 LUTS and 57 slices registers, I will be using 22 slices. Some slices aren't fully used, so this will make slice usage go higher. Also extra slices will be used to meet timing constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed correct in your edit.
The synthesizer is sometimes a very unpredictable thing, and especially what your constraints are and what you optimize for is key in getting results.

If you were to optimize for size (area) your estimates might be closer.
The bigger and more complex your systems are, the greater this will effect your final place and route. This is why, when you look at your small example, results are closer.

This is also a fine reason why you shouldn't "fill up" your FPGA.
The more space you have left, the more efficient in closing timing the optimizer can be.
This is of course a "waste" of resources, but might lead to better results.

One advice I have received regarding FPGA layout is to not go into such detail that the synthesizer doesn't have room to operate. E.g. Don't make a flip flop out of logic, use the abstraction of the language instead. As long as you are aware of how the results are reached let the synthesizer do its job of finding out what is necessary and how to optimize it, it usually does a better job

\Paul

Answer (score 0):

In the Xilinx toolchain, the build step in which LUTs and registers are assigned to specific slices is called "map". By default, and especially if your design occupies only a small amount of the device's resources, map will not try to pack as many LUTs and registers into a slice as it possibly could. This is why you're seeing a higher slice count than expected.

You can force map to pack slices more agressively by setting the -c (Pack Slices) option to 1:

> -c [packfactor ]
>
> The packfactor (for non-zero values) is the target slice density
>   percentage.
>
> - A packfactor value of 0 specifies that only related logic (logic having signals in common) should be packed into a single Slice, and
>     yields the least densely packed design.
> - A packfactor of 1 results in maximum packing density as the packer is attempting 1% slice utilization.
> - A packfactor of 100 means that only enough unrelated packs will occur to fit the device with 100% utilization. This results in minimum
>     packing density.